# Drag and Drop image and display image on gridlayout - Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm new to kivy and I'm trying to create a drag and drop app where if the image is dropped onto the gridlayout the image is shown on the app as shown below. I'm trying to get the file_path of the image and then using the file_path to display it on the gridlayout but unfortunately, that is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the current image [image]

This is what I want after dragging the image [image]

Kv file

```
# Custom button
<CustButton@Button>:
    font_size: 32
    background_normal: 'Colour_yellow.png'
    background_down: 'Colour_blue.png'

<Cust2@Button>:
    font_size: 32
    background_normal: 'Colour_red.png'
    background_down: 'Colour_blue.png'

<Cust3@Button>:
    font_size: 32
    background_normal: 'Colour_white.png'
    background_down: 'Colour_blue.png'

<Cust4@Button>:
    font_size: 32
    background_normal: 'Colour_blue.png'
    background_down: 'Colour_white.png'

<CalcGridLayout>:
    id: calculator
    display: entry
    rows: 5
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 100
        size_hint: .5, None
        Cust2:
            text: "Whats the intensity you want?"

    BoxLayout:

        size_hint: .5, None
        TextInput:
            id: entry
            font_size: 70
            multiline: False
            hint_text: "Type here"

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 100
        size_hint: .5, None
        Cust4:
            text: "Drag and Drop picture below:"
            on_release: root.build1()

    #THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK ON
    BoxLayout:
        Image:
            source: root._on_file_drop(file_path)

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, .3
        spacing: 10

        CustButton:
            text: "Click here for \n reduced size"

        CustButton:
            text: "Click here for pos \n  and intensity of \n      each pixel"
            on_release: root.reduced_image()

        CustButton:
            text: "Click here \n for graph"

        CustButton:
            text: "Click here \n     for all"

        CustButton:
            text: "Extra"
```

Python file

```
import kivy

kivy.require("1.9.0")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)


class CalcGridLayout(GridLayout):

    def reduced_image(self):
    #ignore

    def build1(self):
        Window.bind(on_dropfile=self._on_file_drop)
        return

    def _on_file_drop(self, window, file_path):
        print(file_path)
        return file_path



class dropdownApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return CalcGridLayout()


dropApp = dropdownApp()
dropApp.run()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution

Please refer to the snippets, and complete example for details.

### kv file

1. Remove `on_release: root.build1()`
2. Replace `source: root._on_file_drop(file_path)` with `id: img`

#### Snippet

```
BoxLayout:
    spacing: 100
    size_hint: .5, None
    Cust4:
        text: "Drag and Drop picture below:"

BoxLayout:
    Image:
        id: img
```

### Python Code

1. Add import statement, `from kivy.properties import StringProperty`
2. Declare property, `filePath = StringProperty('')` in `class CalcGridLayout()`.
3. Add *constructor* to `class CalcGridLayout()` and move `Window.bind(on_dropfile=self._on_file_drop)` from `build1()` method
4. Remove `build1()` method
5. In `_on_file_drop()` method, replace `return file_path` with `self.filePath = file_path.decode("utf-8")` `self.ids.img.source = self.filePath` and `self.ids.img.reload()`

#### Snippet

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
...

class CalcGridLayout(GridLayout):
    filePath = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CalcGridLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_dropfile=self._on_file_drop)

    def reduced_image(self):
        print(self.filePath)

    def _on_file_drop(self, window, file_path):
        print(file_path)
        self.filePath = file_path.decode("utf-8")     # convert byte to string
        self.ids.img.source = self.filePath
        self.ids.img.reload()   # reload image
```

[Window » on_dropfile Event](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html?highlight=window#kivy.core.window.WindowBase.on_dropfile)

> ```
> on_dropfile(filename)
> ```
>
> Event called when a file is dropped on the application.
>
> ***Warning***
>
> This event currently works with sdl2 window provider, on pygame window
>   provider and OS X with a patched version of pygame. This event is left
>   in place for further evolution (ios, android etc.)

## Example

### main.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.11.0")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)


class CalcGridLayout(GridLayout):
    filePath = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CalcGridLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_dropfile=self._on_file_drop)

    def reduced_image(self):
        print(self.filePath)

    def _on_file_drop(self, window, file_path):
        print(file_path)
        self.filePath = file_path.decode("utf-8")     # convert byte to string
        self.ids.img.source = self.filePath
        self.ids.img.reload()   # reload image


class DragDropApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return CalcGridLayout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    DragDropApp().run()
```

### dragdrop.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

# Custom button
<CustButton@Button>:
    background_normal: "/home/iam/Pictures/AppImages/Colors/yellow.png"   # 'Colour_yellow.png'
    background_down: "/home/iam/Pictures/AppImages/Colors/blue.png"       # 'Colour_blue.png'
    text_size: self.size
    halign: 'center'
    valign: 'middle'

<Cust2@Button>:
    font_size: 32
    background_normal: "/home/iam/Pictures/AppImages/Colors/red.png"   # 'Colour_red.png'
    background_down: "/home/iam/Pictures/AppImages/Colors/blue.png"     # 'Colour_blue.png'

<Cust3@Button>:
    font_size: 32
    background_normal: "/home/iam/Pictures/AppImages/Colors/white.png"     # 'Colour_white.png'
    background_down: "/home/iam/Pictures/AppImages/Colors/blue.png"       # 'Colour_blue.png'

<Cust4@Button>:
    font_size: 32
    background_normal: "/home/iam/Pictures/AppImages/Colors/blue.png"     # 'Colour_blue.png'
    background_down: "/home/iam/Pictures/AppImages/Colors/white.png"       # 'Colour_white.png'

<CalcGridLayout>:
    id: calculator
    display: entry
    rows: 5
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 100
        size_hint: .5, None
        Cust2:
            text: "Whats the intensity you want?"

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: .5, None
        TextInput:
            id: entry
            font_size: 70
            multiline: False
            hint_text: "Type here"

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 100
        size_hint: .5, None
        Cust4:
            text: "Drag and Drop picture below:"

    BoxLayout:
        Image:
            id: img

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, .3
        spacing: 10

        CustButton:
            text: "Click here for \n reduced size"

        CustButton:
            text: "Click here for pos \n  and intensity of \n      each pixel"
            on_release: root.reduced_image()

        CustButton:
            text: "Click here \n for graph"

        CustButton:
            text: "Click here \n     for all"

        CustButton:
            text: "Extra"
```

## Output

[image: Img01]
[image: Img02]

Comment: Thank you so much! How would I be able to use the filepath in the other function `def reduced_image(self):`?

Comment: @AbidAbdulGafoor: Please refer to my updated post for saving and accessing `file_path`. Please remember to mark the answer as accepted, and/or vote on the answer. Thank you.